# Does the Bytecode class file contains JRElibrary functions?

Tags: java, static-libraries, bytecode

Suppose there is a simple java program:

```
package pkg;
import java.lang.System;
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("\nhello, world\n good");
        System.out.println(args.length);
    }
}
```

After compilation, I get A.class, the bytecode file. I want to know whether A.class contains the library function println? I know for sure in C++/C the EXE will contain library functions (not the DLL version).

A derived question is how the JVM get function println? Is it a dynamic loading when JVM interprets the corresponding statement "System.out.println(...)" from specified JRE routine. Or just execute the the println contained in A.class file?

---

> EDIT: Can I say JAVA IS DYNAMICALLY LINKING STANDARD LIBRARIES? –

Comment: No , the JVM or JRE will have the relevant class files which contains the library functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know whether A.class contains the library function println?

No it doesn't.  If you are keen, you can use the `javap` command (or a decompiler) to see what is inside a class file.

> A derived question is how the JVM get function println?

It is loaded from the "rt.jar" file that forms part of the JRE / JDK you are using to run the program.

That's one reason why you need to install a JRE/JDK to run Java code ...

Comment: "That's why you need to install a JRE/JDK to run Java code". It's certainly one reason. It's not the only reason.

Comment: I am curious why the JAVA API is included in the JRE. Now I get the answer. The JVM, JIT as well, needs library class bytecode to interpret the function call.

Comment: Technically, `rt.jar` is named differently on macs.

Comment: Can I say JAVA IS DYNAMICALLY LINKING STANDARD LIBRARIES?

Comment: It depends precisely what you mean by dynamically linking.  But that would not be an unreasonable description of what is happening.

Comment: @Zachery Yes you can. Moreover, all libraries are dynamically linked. More precisely, the unit of linking is a class file, not library.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Many thanks for detailed exploration. In my A.java program, I only use the println method of out. So during dynamic linking, is the whole System.class loaded into memory? Or just loading either the println() or out class file(PrintStream.java)?

Comment: @StephenC Could you give me some hints for question above?

Comment: @Zachery - the class is the smallest unit of loading in Java.

Comment: @StephenC I see. The class file is loaded into the Method Area in heap. Then corresponding constant_pool was generated.

Comment: @Zachery - Yea ... sort of.  Your terminology is wrong, but you have the right idea.

Comment: @Zachary "The whole System.class" is not very big.